# meta viewport breaking pinch/zoom on mobile

Tags: mobile, viewport

I'm working on a mobile site that needs to allow the user to pinch to zoom the page. When I add the meta viewport tag below, and many variations of it, the page does not allow zooming.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, user-scalable=1">
```

If I remove the tag all together I get the page to allow zooming, however it's initial zoom level is very small and almost unreadable. Yes I understand I am allowing the user to zoom, but the initial page should be readable to most humans, not something around 5px font-size as it is now. Any help on what the issue with the viewport settings need to be to work would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen "user-scalable" have a value of "1". I believe the default is for it to be on, so try removing that portion all together.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2">
```